# Why is the Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation also called the "Feynman trick"?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology

The Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation is a nice way of eliminating squared terms in an exponential. It is heavily used in statistical mechanics. Essentially it boils down to the simple identity:

$$\mathrm{e}^{\lambda a^{2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-x^{2}/2+\sqrt{2\lambda}ax}\mathrm{d}x$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubbard%E2%80%93Stratonovich_transformation) cites some references to works of Hubbard and Stratonovich justifying its name.

But I have also seen this transformation called "Feynman's trick", for example in these papers:

- Supplementary materials of the paper https://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.048103.
- https://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0305-4608/5/5/017

Although there are many things named "Feynman trick", for this in particular I could not find any Feynman paper actually exploiting this transformation. Can someone point to some references?

Comment: I believe it's on *you* to provide some references. Where did you hear someone referring to that transformation as "Feynman's trick"? I could just claim it is also known as the "AFT trick", and ask people to justify that terminology, but that would be pretty off-topic, don't you think?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform See the supplementary materials to this paper: 10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.048103. Just look for "Feynman".

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate it if you included that reference in the post itself (and, if possible, a second reference, by different authors, so as to be sure it wasn't just a lapsus by Tikhonov and Monasson).

Comment: AFT trick is called the Cooley-Tukey algorithm.

Comment: According to his books, Feynman liked doing hard integrals and particularly liked this trick. So I guess that plus the tendency of people to hero-worship caused the term "Feynman's trick" to stick.

Comment: @DanielSank `Feynman liked doing hard integrals and particularly liked this trick`. Can you point to a paper/book where Feynman uses this trick? Does he credit someone else?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Unfortunately I cannot find another right now. I could swear I saw this in a few other papers. But maybe you are right and it was just a mistake by Tikhonov et al.

Comment: @becko I only know about this because of Feynman's own words in one of his books. I don't remember exactly which book mentions this, unfortunately.

Comment: I know a completely different relation by the name of Feynman's trick:
$$ \frac{1}{a^\alpha b^\beta} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \int_0^1 \frac{x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}}{(ax+b(1-x))^{\alpha+\beta}}$$ I believe that just any mathematical trick that was presented by Feynman in his lectures could be dubbed 'Feynman's trick' by his students.

Comment: @DanielSank I think that refers to a different trick (see Adam's comment).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I included another reference!

Comment: @becko I cannot point to a paper or book where the trick is used. I just remember reading, in one of Feynman's own books about his life, that he was fond of this trick.